# Sequelize how to return destroyed row

Tags: node.js, row, sequelize.js, destroy

Here is my code for deleting rows in database

```
Model.destroy({
  where: {
    ...
  }
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

What I am getting in `console.log` is `0` or `1`  whether record deleted or not..

Is it any way to return destroyed row in promise?

So response should be like this { id:123, ... }

Comment: Added some updates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Update` and `Destroy` do not work that way. So you cannot, but there is a way.

```
Model.find({
   where: {...}
}).then((result) => {
    return Model.destroy({where: ..})
              .then((u) => {return result});
});
```

Here we are returning a promise as `Model.destroy` which will resolve to `result` object received from the call to `Model.find`.

So, let us say there is a function called `deleteRow` defined as:

```
function deleteRow() {
    return Model.find({
        where: { ...}
    }).then((result) => {
        return Model.destroy({ where: ..})
            .then((u) => { return result });
    });
}
```

You could use `deleteRow` as:

```
deleteRow().then(findResult => console.log(JSON.stringify(findResult));
```

Comment: Thank you Suhail.. have't implemented yet but I believe it will be fine... So are you sure that there is no way of retrieve deleted record without  2 query?

Comment: You could use a backup file, perhaps. I am not aware of any recovery tools available. But this is good.

Comment: Actually `update` works that way with Postgres. See `returnign: true` option

Comment: This answer is incorrect because of concurrency. The number of records during the find() and the destroy() operations aren't always the same.

Comment: two queries have to be made just to get the returning data, not really optimize as I see